# JS dynamically-added content not showing at specific screen size (CSS/Layout?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've got this interesting bug that has got me stumped. I've got a JS timer that is counting down until Christmas. It's working as expected. It dynamically updates the content of the Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds divs. It shows correctly in all screen sizes except for this range: 737px - 766px (see screen shot).

[image: Broken timer on page].

For some reason, the divs collapse and show no numbers. However if I use my Google Developer Tools - Console, I can confirm that the numbers are in fact being deposited into the divs (see screen shot below).

[image: Google Dev Tools - Console]

For some reason that I can't pinpoint, the numbers don't show in this screen size range. The code is below:

```
<style>
.ct-increment-container {
   border: 3px solid #eb1c24;
   border-radius: 10px;
   display: block;#eb1c24;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 7px;
}
#ct-days, #ct-hours, #ct-minutes, #ct-seconds {
   font: 40px "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
   font-weight: 500;
   line-height: 1;
   color: black;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 5px;
}
.ct-increment-container .ct-label {
   background-color: #eb1c24;
   color: white;
   font-size: 11px;
   font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
   padding: 3px 0 1px;
}
.ct-msg {
    clear: both;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
   #cmas-timer {
      display: table;
      margin-top: -8px;
   }
   .ct-msg { 
      display: table-cell; 
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-size: 26px;
   }
}
@media (min-width: 959px) and (max-width: 1025px) {
   .top-banner {
      height: 125px;
   }
   #cmas-timer {
      margin-top: -8px;
   }
   .ct-msg { 
      display: block;
      padding-top: 5px;
      font-size: 20px;
   }
}

@media (max-width: 959px) {
   #cmas-timer {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -135px;
   }
   .ct-msg { 
      display: block;
      padding-top: 5px;
      font-size: 20px;
   }
}
@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 959px) {
   .top-banner {
      margin-top: 135px;
   }
   #cmas-timer {
      top: -116px;
   }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   div#main {
      margin-top: 110px;
   }
   #cmas-timer {
      top: 95px;
   }
}
</style>

<div id="cmas-timer">
   <div class="ct-increment-container">
      <div id="ct-days"><!-- Javascript prints days here --></div>
      <div class="ct-label">Days</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ct-increment-container">
      <div id="ct-hours"><!-- Javascript prints hours here --></div>
      <div class="ct-label">Hours</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ct-increment-container">
      <div id="ct-minutes"><!-- Javascript prints minutes here --></div>
      <div class="ct-label">Minutes</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ct-increment-container">
      <div id="ct-seconds"><!-- Javascript prints seconds here --></div>
      <div class="ct-label">Seconds</div>
   </div>
   <div class="ct-msg">'Til Christmas</div>
</div>


<script>
var deadline = 'December 24 2017 23:59:59';
function getTimeRemaining(){
  var t = Date.parse(deadline) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}
function pad(n) {
    return (n < 10) ? ("0" + n) : n;
}
function updateClock(){
  var t = getTimeRemaining();
  document.getElementById("ct-days").innerHTML = pad(t.days);
  document.getElementById("ct-hours").innerHTML = pad(t.hours);
  document.getElementById("ct-minutes").innerHTML = pad(t.minutes);
  document.getElementById("ct-seconds").innerHTML = pad(t.seconds);
  if(t.total<=0){
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
  }
}

updateClock(); // run function once at first to avoid delay
var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
</script>
```

Comment: `#cmas-timer {
      top: -116px;
   }` ?

Comment: A style to compensate for styles that I cannot touch on the website. It applies to sizes higher than my problem size, so I wouldn't think this was a problem...?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `top` property?

Comment: No, because that style doesn't apply at sizes below 767px.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a link to live page/demo, because your code works fine, you can clearly see that here - https://jsfiddle.net/ncsresjw/

It is just jumping due to positioning rules, for example:

```
#cmas-timer {
   top: -116px;
}
```

So, there must be something else affecting the text and it not possible to determine the cause just from one screenshot and one (working) snippet.